# xmlhttprequest cannot load no access control allow origin header is present- country.asmx/GetCountries web service

Tags: javascript, web-services

I tries to access external web service from pure js. Why I get error "xmlhttprequest cannot load no access control allow origin header is present" for my web service. Any idea to overcome this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        $('#output').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its a security restriction (same-origin-policy) you would need to use Ajax to call a script on your server that calls that API and returns it.

Comment: That URL is slow and returns XML filled with *escaped* XML? ( &lt;Name&gt;Tuvalu&lt;/Name&gt;)

Comment: Is it just a list of countries? I would expect that to be quite a constant data set ...

Comment: Same error I for all webservices. Is there any browser/ machine config need to be done to solve this?